# Fresh Bootstrap MVC4 installation build errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, controller, twitter-bootstrap-3, build-error

EDIT: I found the answer to this while I was writing up the question so I will answer it here in case anyone has the same problem

I just created a new MVC4 application (Intranet) and installed Bootstrap from the package manager console (install-package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4) and overwrote the homecontroller.cs when it asked me if I wanted to.

It opened the readme.txt and mentioned that if I had build errors mentioning the "Web" and "MvcTextTemplateHost" namespaces missing to close and reopen the solution. So I tried to build and I got a number of errors, a number of which mentioned missing the HomeController.cs (which did exist in the controllers folder). So I closed and reopened and tried to rebuild but the errors were still there.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently if you install twitter.bootstrap.mvc4 through the package manager you also have to install the twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.sample package.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/524225/Twitter-Bootstrap-MVC4-the-Bootstrap-package-for-A